# BODMAS riddle - which is correct?

Tags: arithmetic

I fully understand the order of BODMAS - It's the order of operations in maths equations.

So lately this little puzzle/riddle has been going around on social media - [url=http://9gag.com/gag/ab0y1br?ref=fbp]Solve carefully - 9GAG[/url] . I understand that it's a play on grammar because they actually mean $5!$ as in the factorial.

The thing i notice is that some people argue that the answer is $-180$ and others argue that it's $120$ - for the simple adding and subtracting, not the factorial itself.

$$25-55+(85+65) =25-55+(150) =25-205 =-180.$$

Others state
$$ 25-55+(85+65) =25-55+(150) =-55+150+25 =-55+175 =120.$$

Which is correct and why?

Thanks

Ps. I feel quite silly for asking this.

Comment: **A**dd or **S**ubtract FROM LEFT TO RIGHT

Comment: "I fully understand the order of BODMAS" ...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 There is no need to get aggressive with the OP. They admit that they understand the ORDER of BODMAS. That does not mean they knows how to apply it in every situation. This is a site for clarification, and this is what they are asking for.

Comment: With the add or subtract from left to right.....Is there a real reason for this? Or is it purely just to give people a starting point?

Comment: "Is there a reason for this?" - yes, it is a **standard**. In theory, everyone adhering to the standard will arrive at the same result given the same starting point.

Comment: Way too many downvotes here! We should be welcoming newbies and helping them learn.

Comment: "put on hold as off-topic" - Ha ha....don't make me laugh! This is a perfectly good question and doesn't need any alteration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just asking about $25-55+(85+65)$, then the correct answer should be $120$. Note that to get your other answer of $-180$, you would also need a negative sign in front of $(85+65)$; since there is only a single minus sign, the only term being subtracted off is $55$, so you can compute it as 
$$
25-55+(85+65)$=25+150-55=175-55=120.
$$

Comment: Ah yes. I see what's happened. They've cheekily swapped a sign around, i didn't notice that. So it should be 25 - -95 instead of 25 - 205. That was bugging me why it gave two answers, and so i thought there was a intricate rule about BODMAS that would give the different answer if not considered.

Answer (score 1):

$$
120 = 5!
$$

is correct.

$$
  25-55+(150) \ne 25-205.
$$

For that to be true you'd need another set of parentheses:
$$
  25-(55+(150)) = 25-205.
$$

Comment: I'm not asking about the factorial! I'm asking about the order of operation of the equation and whether it's 120 or -180. May you expand further please?

Comment: You know that it's called *the order of operations* - why not just follow the rules? Is $3 + 2 \cdot 4 = 24$? No.

Comment: Chaz - I'm asking for clarity of the rules. Clearly, there is something that misunderstand.

Comment: I would give this answer a thumbs up but i need more reputation on this site.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example, you do not need the brackets since $a+b+(c+d)=a+b+c+d$. In our case, we can directly add and subtract the numbers. $$25-55+(85+65)=25-55+85+65=120=5!$$

The order of operations states to evaluate brackets first. In our case, the brackets are evaluated by performing addition, which is a associative. Thus, we can drop the brackets and add directly.

Comment: I would give this answer a thumbs up but i need more reputation on this site.

Comment: Don't worry about that. I just wanted to make sure you read the answer in case it was the associativity that was tripping you up. You can always come back, if you want.

Comment: It's nice to give people credit, where credit is due!